# General Fake Coin: k fake coins out of n coins

Tags: mathematics, weighing, algorithm

Considering a general fake coin problem. There are $n$ coins in total and $k$ of them are fake. Fake coins are lighter than the normal ones. You only have a balance to compare two groups of coins (no amount limit). How many times you will compare at least?

Note: All the fake coins have the same weight $w_f$; all the good coins have the same weight $w_g$; $w_f < w_g$; The target is to find all the fake coins using minimum time complexity (expected $O(\log n)$).

Comment: Is the value of $k$ known beforehand ?

Comment: @Evargalo Yes, the $k$ is a known constant here. We can suppose $k <= \frac{n}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

For $n$ coins of which $k$ are fake, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ potential assignments. Each weighing has three possible results (left heavier, right heavier, equal). So at least $\left\lceil \log_3\binom{n}{k
}\right\rceil$ weighings are required to distinguish between the possibilities.

Comment: I think the number of weighing rounds is correct theoretically, but can you please provide some details of how to weigh them in each round pratically?

Comment: This is a theoretical minimum, I don't think it can always be achieved.

Comment: @FlorianF hm, interesting, I first read this answer as "the minimum number of weighings is at least this much". But I can see how it can also mean "the minimum is this much".